# Recovering vertex names from Combinatorica Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages

According to WRI tech support:

*Combinatorica functionality is not technically deprecated,
though it is our hope that future versions of Mathematica will subsume it
entirely by incorporating its functionality with the built-in Graphs &
Networks functionality.*

Leaving aside that this seems to conflict with MMA's documentation, eg:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]
```

warns:

*General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.*

In the meantime, in order to use Combinatorica functionality like TransitiveClosure on built in Graphs, it's necessary to take a detour through Combinatorica, eg:

```
AdjacencyGraph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &@
 Combinatorica`ToAdjacencyMatrix@
  Combinatorica`RemoveSelfLoops@
   Combinatorica`TransitiveClosure@
    Combinatorica`FromAdjacencyMatrix@
     Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@Graph[{"E0" -> "T0", "T0" -> "E1"}]
```

This yields (sorry for truncation):

[image]

How to recover the built in Graph's vertex names? (These are extracted from XML metadata and so it's not so convenient to project them to positional indices)

Comment: hmm... unless explicitly provided, `PropertyValue` does not return the `VertexLabels` or any of `VertexList`, `EdgeList`, etc. Since `Graph` is atomic, one can't do structural manipulations either... Do you have control over how the first `Graph` is created (the one with E0, T0)? I think it might be possible to project them to positional indices easily, if that's a route you'd consider.

Comment: It's ok to map vertex names to numbers - that's what's happening in Combinatorica's representation anyway - as long as the process is invertible. Subsequent pattern matching is done on the vertex names (which are part of Rules that map to other XML attributes etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `VertexList` of the input graph as the first argument in `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
g1 = Graph[{"E0"->"T0","E0"->"E1","T0"->"E1"}, VertexLabels->"Name",ImagePadding->10];
g2 = AdjacencyGraph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10] &@ AdjacencyMatrix@g1;
g3 = AdjacencyGraph[VertexList[g1], #, VertexLabels -> "Name",ImagePadding -> 10]&
     @AdjacencyMatrix@g1;
Grid[{{"g1", "g2", "g3"}, {g1, g2, g3}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

EDIT: Alternative methods using `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue`:

```
 g4 = g2; 
 PropertyValue[g4, VertexLabels] =Thread[VertexList[g4] -> VertexList[g1]];
 g5 = SetProperty[g2, VertexLabels -> Thread[VertexList[g2] -> VertexList[g1]]];
 Grid[{{"g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5"}, {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5}},Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I just noticed that I was sloppy w/ the specification -  somehow Normal@Adjacency matrix preserves direction but Combinatorica`FromAdjacencyMatrix[#,Type->Directed] doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: The option value should be a string: that is, `FromAdjacencyMatrix[#,Type->"Directed"][{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}]` works.

Comment: I had tried "Directed" -it still yields an undirected graph. ??

Comment: @alancalvitti to preserve direction you could use `ToCombinatoricaGraph` in the ``GraphUtilities` `` package instead of ``Combinatorica`FromAdjacencyMatrix@Normal@Combinatorica`AdjacencyMatrix``